# How to speed up split(string) in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a large dataset(480k+ records) on HDFS and i want to split each record by \t.

Here is my code:

```
static JavaPairRDD<String, String> load(JavaSparkContext sc, String path) throws Exception {
    JavaRDD<String> wholeData = sc.textFile(path);
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> wholeDataRDD = wholeData.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws Exception {
            List<String> line = Arrays.asList(Pattern.compile("\t").split(s));
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(line.get(0), line.get(1));
        }
    });
    return wholeDataRDD;
}
```

The above code can work but it is too slow(about 9min).

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @stefanobaghino spark2.1.0 and java1.8

Comment: How does it perform locally? I tried it on a local file with a million entry and it scanned through it in a little more then a second (included all the overhead that Spark introduces in these cases). Furthermore: is this just a test? Otherwhise for 480k+ records it's probably easier (and faster) to just run something that gets the file on a single machine and runs the process on a single node.

Comment: how large is the string being passed to your anonymous `Tuple2` class?

Comment: @stefanobaghino Thank you! It is very fast in local[100](about 1 second),but very slow on yarn(200 executors)

Comment: @Bohemian less than 30 letters for each record

Comment: I would suggest you remove the `[100]`, you can just say `local` and a proper amount of executors will be created (100 won't do any good). You may want to check what else the bottleneck can be (network? disk?). There can be a million different answers but your code is not a problem, per se.

Comment: You could make it about 10x faster with `static Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\t");` and then `String[] line = splitter.split(s));             return new Tuple2<String, String>(line[0], line[1]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

1. As @Bohemian mentioned in comment, you should write static field `static Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\t");` and then `String[] line = splitter.split(s));` in anonymous class
2. Probably parallelization is wrong. It means that you may have too many or too less partitions or too many or too less executors. As mentioned in comments, too many executors can be a bottleneck - in your case, 200 executors is very high number. I suggest to check partition number by `RDD.getNumPartitions()` - probably is not bigger than 200. Remember that each executor is a new JVM and transfer data to other JVM is very slow IO operation. If you don't know how many executors you should have - don't worry! Spark as [Dynamic Allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)

Comment: Thank you! I reduce num_executors to 100 and the time reduced from 9min to 2.7min.